# A problem occurred evaluating root project android

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am running a flutter project. I may have a exception about gradle build. The exception is as follow.

The project url : https://github.com/muxable/rtchat. I am building the rtchat 1.5.5.

My env is Flutter 2.10.2, Java 11, android-studio-2022.2.1.20-windows, gradle 7.5.1.

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\flutter_crash_production\rtchat-1.5.5\rtchat-1.5.5\android\build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'E:\flutter_crash_production\rtchat-1.5.5\rtchat-1.5.5\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\loqigd\.gradle\caches\7.0.2\scripts\37xgvd950ehzckgpodd04h6vz).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I try to set the env of the project as gradle 7.5.1, but the exception is not fix.